# Not showing organic keyword when using desktop browser

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I'm newbie on `google analytics` if I organic search on using laptop browsers not showing `organic keyword` on `google analytics`, but when I organic search on using mobile browsers then showing `organic keyword` like below:

[image]

How can I reach this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged into Google, their query is conducted over SSL and the referral data relating to the search isn't shown. I'm guessing you were logged into your Google account on your desktop but not your phone.

Comment: Not only one desktop / laptop, another 2 or 3 desktop / laptop which is not to me

Comment: Alex L's answer is correct, but Google searches are now over SSL by default, even when not logged in. The only supported way to get information about organic keywords is using the Google Search Console.

Comment: In addition to looking at top landing pages in GA (assuming you have pages targeting specific keywords)